# is it possible to send email with custom view instead of presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, smtp, smtpclient, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i need to send email in my application.

i know that this can be possible using MFMailComposeViewController.

But it popup [presentModalViewController](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e2fbf214c6.gif),I need to custom reception box,composer,subject [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7be9dd218c.png).

simply by clicking send button i need to send email.

if it is possible can ant one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security and privacy reasons, Apple does not allow applications to send automatically email, and requires the user to review it and explicitly click on the Send button in order to do it.

If a regular app could present its own view to get the email data and send it, what's to stop a malicious app from sending spam emails on the user behalf to all his contacts?

Comment: This would be an awesome way to earn money. Who needs iAd if you have iSpam?!

Answer (score 1):

Franci is right that Apple's frameworks do not allow this, but it can be done. You need to link in a custom SMTP framework to do it.

This is an example.
http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

I have not used that particular framework. Googling will probably provide many other options.

Comment: thank u xyzzycoder,i found most of the people face problems using this framework.

Comment: So, I take back the "have not used" bit. I have used it on one project. It worked fine for our purposes.

Comment: Note that you might be able to send an email this way, but you won't be able to send it on e user's behalf (from their email address), unless you find another way to obtain their address.

Answer (score 0):

There's no background mail-sending class in Cocoa, but if you reallllly need to, you can build your own.  A lot of mail servers will let you send mail anonymously.  Read on up on the SMTP protocol, then pick a mail server and telnet into it and test it out.  Then you can use network classes in Cocoa to follow the protocol programatically.  It's a bit of a pain, but I've done it before.

Useful links:
[NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSStream)
[NSInpoutStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[NSOutputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[SMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

To telnet into a server, pick a mail server, then in terminal, type `telnet <server> 25` and press Enter.  Then follow the protocol.